Is there a way to programmatically determine whether a publication's source is local to the Archive host?
I'm working on a library that wraps Aeron and is meant to make it straightforward for a publisher to record its own publication via the ::aeron::archive::client::startRecording method. This method requires a SourceLocation, however, and our current thinking is that we'd like to allow the publisher to run on both the Archive host and off of it. But rather than have the caller provide this SourceLocation, I was wondering whether there was some way to inspect the publication object and the Archive object and figure this out programmatically.
My original thought was to compare the interface present in the Archive's control channel and the interface present within the publisher's primary channel. If we restrict the call of startRecording to the publishing program, then we can also inspect the interfaces present on that machine and see whether the Archive's interface is present there. I'm not quite sure whether that'd work, and certainly if there's a recommended approach, I'd be happy to follow it.
